# Adding User Inputs in placeholder

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

This is from BootStrap 3's website:

```
User input
Use the <kbd> to indicate input that is typically entered via keyboard.

To switch directories, type <kbd>cd</kbd> followed by the name of the directory.<br>
To edit settings, press <kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd></kbd>
```

How do you incorporate them into placeholders (background text inside input fields)?

```
$j('#text_input').attr('placeholder','Enter options and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> key');
```

The above code does not change the text styling. It treats it as literally < kbd>Enter< /kbd>

Comment: The placeholder attribute can only contain text, not HTML markup. (cfr. http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html)

Comment: what if i want to do HTML markup? is there any special way i could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how it could be done with HTML markup instead of using the `placeholder` attribute. But this seems like more work than it may be worth.

1. Position an element over the top of the input
2. Hide and show the element on focus\blur
3. Make sure to set focus on the input if the placeholder is clicked.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/fe86t8hs/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="input-wrap">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
    <span class="placeholder">Enter options and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> key</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.input-wrap { position: relative; }
.placeholder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 6px;    
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.placeholder').click(function(){
   $(this).prev().focus(); 
});

$('.form-control').focus(function() {
   $(this).next().hide();
});

$('.form-control').blur(function() {
   if($(this).val() == "")
      $(this).next().show();
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Geez, why would you even bothered. What I meant is thanks a lot for your kindest effort. (: